# Why is Microsoft.Threading.Tasks needed at runtime?

Tags: .net, azure, portable-class-library, base-class-library

I deployed a solution to Azure to find that `Microsoft.Threading.Tasks` was missing and the application could not load.

One of my referenced projects I use the portable stuff

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<packages>
  <package id="Microsoft.Bcl" version="1.1.9" targetFramework="portable-net45+sl50+win+wp80" developmentDependency="true" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Bcl.Async" version="1.0.168" targetFramework="portable-net45+sl50+win+wp80" developmentDependency="true" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Bcl.Build" version="1.0.14" targetFramework="portable-net45+sl50+win+wp80" developmentDependency="true" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Net.Http" version="2.2.22" targetFramework="portable-net45+sl50+win+wp80" developmentDependency="true" />
  <package id="Newtonsoft.Json" version="6.0.3" targetFramework="portable-net45+sl50+win+wp80" />
</packages>
```

and I marked those as `developmentDependency` such my main project don't include these portables. I was under the impression that a .NET 4.5 application would not need the portable packages as they already should be in the core of .NET and the BCL stuff was only needed at build time.

Is my assumption wrong? Should I still include `Microsoft.Bcl.Build` and `Microsoft.Bcl.Async` in my .NET 4.5 applications?

Comment: Why are you including `Microsoft.Bcl.Async` at all if you are targeting 4.5? Those packages are to allow .NET 4.0 projects access .NET 4.5 features (async/await and some other calls).

Comment: The portable library needs them to be able to support the features for the non 4.5 projects. Portal project B depends on the above stuff, my library A depends on B and is a 4.5 and I wonder why my 4.5 app also needs the above stuff.

Answer (score 2):

The issue is your library was compiled to talk to "something" inside `Microsoft.Threading.Tasks` (and actually you will likely need to include `Microsoft.Threading.Tasks`, `Microsoft.Threading.Tasks.Extensions`, and `Microsoft.Threading.Tasks.Extensions.Desktop` in your deployment). If you are on .NET 4.5 the code in those 3 DLLs know just to forward the call on to the NET framework, if you are on .NET 4.0 it does its replacement calls.

Your compiled DLL's "Imports" (to use a C term) does not change depending on its runtime environment. Your program always has to make a call in to that proxy, the proxy may do very little on a 4.5 system, but the call still has to happen.